# How to initialize Foundation 6 Javascript correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

my Javascript of Foundation is not working. I think my initialization is wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
var jQ = $.noConflict();
jQ(document).foundation();

jQ(document).ready(function($){
    var orbit = new Foundation.Orbit($('#slider'), {animation: 'fade',
        timerDelay: 8000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        navButtons: false,
        bullets: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you shouldn't set it through JS like this but rather in your HTML in the `data-options`, more [info](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html#js-options).

Example:

```
<div class="orbit" role="region" data-orbit data-options="timerDelay:5000; pauseOnHover:true;navButtons:false;bullets:false;">
...
</div>
```

You can find specific information for Foundation 6 here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html

Comment: yes. I have the right html, but i want to change the settings because i have different sliders on the page

Comment: Hi Thanks, But nothing changed. There are still buttons and navButtons. Because I have $.noConflict(). Could that be the error there?

Comment: Okay. Here is it. It´s for an ebaytheme. The javascript is loading asynchron. https://jsbin.com/cadazuvosi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

That´s my code. No Change :/

```
<div id="slider" class="orbit" role="region" data-options="navButtons:false; autoPlay:false" data-orbit>
    <ul class="orbit-container">

        <li class="orbit-slide is-active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750&text=1st">
        </li>
        <li class="orbit-slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750&text=2nd">
        </li>
        <li class="orbit-slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750&text=3nd">
        </li>
        <li class="orbit-slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x750&text=4nd">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```